# Ionic2 range with blank space

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

How to delete the space between the line under the UPDATE INTERVAL and range itself?

[image]

my code:

```
<div class="range">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>
      update interval
      <ion-badge item-right>{{timePeriod}}</ion-badge>
    </ion-list-header>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-range min="1" max="60" [(ngModel)]="timePeriod">
        <ion-label range-left>1</ion-label>
        <ion-label range-right>60</ion-label>
      </ion-range>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</div>
```

And btw - is it ok to put elements inside the  tag in Ionic2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ion-list-header` element has a margin-bottom, so you can set it to 0 to remove it:

```
ion-list-header.list-header { margin-bottom: 0; }
```

Comment: Really? I tested it on a plunker and worked ok. Could you please inspect the element in Chrome Developer Tools and check if the style rule is being applied?

Comment: ok, now it's ok. Thanks for the solution. What about putting ioninc elemtns inside the <div>?

Comment: Glad to hear that. And regarding the div, It's ok, you can put ionic components inside html default tags like div and span.